# How to prove it's not just a chance finding when testing several variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, sensitivity-analysis

If I tested several similar variables, such as socioeconomic status measures, but only a few were significant, how would I prove that it's not just a chance finding?

Besides having the literature to back it up, is there any sensitivity testing people usually use to prove it's not just chance?

To what degree would I need to consider it may be a chance finding?

I mean, if 2 out of 6 variables are significant, should I be worried? Or it would apply to situations with a much higher number of variables?

Comment: You can obviously never _prove_ that you were unlucky and obtained a "weird" sample. Instead, it seems to me that you are worried about the fact that you included and tested multiple variables. Is that right? Whether or not you need some form of adjustment for that is a contested issue. You may want to look at the questions tagged "multiple comparisons".

Comment: It might be useful to look at this from another perspective. Arguably, it is unlikely for socioeconomic status measures to be completely unrelated, directly or indirectly, to any other measure of human behavior. Whether a difference is “statistically significant” or a correlation is a “chance finding” is therefore not a meaningful question (you know it isn't, there is alway a link however small between any socioeconomic variable and everything else). For one extended version of this argument, you can look up the phrase “crud factor” in a search engine.

Comment: I am not sure about what you mean by “sensitivity testing” but you might be interested into `cross-validation` techniques or `jacknife` or `bootstrap`. You probably should search for more appropriate tags; Sensitivty analysis is something rather different.